# Conditionally Enable Button on TreeNode focus

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following TreeView structure:

[image]

I want to enable the button1 button ("download file(s)") only when the `Scan_XX` or `File_XX` levels in the hierarchy are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AfterSelect` event is a good place for your code.

If you're only concerned with the text of the node, how about this slightly shorter code:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled
       = (e.Node.Text.StartsWith("Scan_") || e.Node.Text.StartsWith("File_"));
}
```

Comment: thanks, I found this in the documentation too, and used an alternative solution based on node level. This is good too, so I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this:

```
 private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Node.Level == 3 || e.Node.Level == 4)
            {
              button1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else {
              button1.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
```